How do I extract a union type from an array of objects in typescript?
I'm trying to derive a union type from a property on an array of objects:
const fontLib = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    subsets: ['latin'],
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    subsets: ['latin'],
  },
] as const;

type FontName = (typeof fontLib)[number]['name'];

type FontName will be 'foo'|'bar' as expected.
But I am trying to add a type annotation of fontLib. This will cause the inferred type to always be the annotated type
const fontLib: FontLib[] = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        subsets: ['latin'],
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        subsets: ['latin'],
    },
] as const;

interface FontLib<T extends string = string> {
    name: T
    subsets: string[];
}

type FontName = (typeof fontLib)[number]['name']; // type FontName is 'string'

How to add type annotations without affecting union type derivation?
Typescript Playground

"How to add type annotations without affecting union type derivation?" You can't. Why do you need such an annotation anyway?

I need to get type hints when adding an item to the arry.

This is expected behavior since a type annotation overrides specific types in the literal that initializes a variable. To ensure a typed literal use satisfies:
Playground
const fontLib = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        subsets: ['latin'],
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        subsets: ['latin'],
    },
] as const satisfies FontLib[];

interface FontLib<T extends string = string> {
    name: T
    subsets: string[];
}

type FontName = (typeof fontLib)[number]['name'];

